# How do I convert a latitude/longitude coordinate to a NOAA GFS grid cell location?

Tags: coordinate-system, noaa

Looking at this GFS http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods/gfs_0p50/gfs20170707/gfs_0p50_12z.ascii?tmax2m[0:2][124:128][279:283]

The range defined by the second and third set of brackets specify the grid coordinates, however I'm not sure how to convert between what NOAA is using and the common geographic coordinate system.

What would the NOAA equivalent be for this coordinate pair: (36.25, -78.75)?

Comment: please can you provide a little more detail on this?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/117749)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this;

[image]

Let's start with these formulas:

```
B3: = 180 + A3 * 2
E3: = IF(D3<0, D3+360, D3)
F3: = E3 * 2
```

And copy the formula through each column.

Give 36.25 to `A5`, -78.75 to `D11`. You will get (252.5) and (562.5).

If you test it, say, [252:253][562:563] then it will be directed to http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods/gfs_0p50/gfs20170707/gfs_0p50_12z.ascii?tmax2m[0:2][252:253][562:563].

Hope this helps.